# How do I begin developing on the Tezos network?

Tags: dapps

Is there a Tezos SDK or something similar? What resources should I look to first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several useful Tools/SDKs, this are some that come to my mind:

https://github.com/TezTech/eztz

https://github.com/maht0rz/tezos-environment-manager

https://github.com/keefertaylor/tezoskit

https://github.com/LMilfont/TezosJ

https://github.com/mscappini/Tz.Net

Answer (score 7):

If you plan to write Smart Contracts, using Liquidity is often simpler than Michelson:

http://www.liquidity-lang.org/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a guide from reddit on how to set up a development environment using a localhost instance of a Tezos network and emac.

https://medium.com/tezsure/setting-up-a-development-environment-for-tezos-36f86c382484